# MySQL updating an unknown number of fields

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

With an INSERT statement I can do something like this, passing in an unknown number of placeholders and values:

```
$insert_SQL = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO laptops ($fields) VALUES ($placeholders)");
$insert_SQL->execute([$values]);
```

Is there a similar method when you're updating a record but don't know the number of values? Something like this:

```
$update_SQL = $db->prepare("UPDATE laptops ($fields) VALUES ($placeholders) WHERE id = $id");
$update_SQL->execute([$values]);
```

Comment: No, there is no similar method.  You need to construct the `set` statement.

Comment: I've got an article on this very topic, [An SQL injection against which prepared statements won't help](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example). Make sure you are using the solution from the last chapter only ;)

Comment: @YourCommonSense thankyou very much - will read asap

Comment: `"update laptops set ".implode('=?,',$fields)."=? where ..."`. if fields string list then `str_replace(',','=?,')`

Comment: @Mike you would benefit from reading that article too.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I do not even think that someone can collect field names directly from the client. Instead of modifying the array of all possible names.

Comment: @Mike check *the very answer below*

Comment: @YourCommonSense so in my case I think I'm okay because (in my example) $fields and $placeholders were hand-typed by me. Only $values comes from external input.

Comment: @daninthemix that's a slippery ground, today it's hand-typed and tomorrow someone would think of an improvement like in the answer below. So it's better be safe than sorry. though it's up to you anyway.

Comment: Placeholders can only represent SINGLE values. What you want is impossible. You either build an sql statement dynamically with as many placeholders you need, or... you figure out some different way of accomplishing what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of.  You could use [REPLACE INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html):

```
$update_SQL = $db->prepare("REPLACE INTO laptops ($fields) ($placeholders)");
$update_SQL->execute([$values]);
```

Caveats:

- `$fields` must include `id`.  `$values` must include `$id`.
- The table must have a primary key or unique index on `id`.  It uses this to determine if a matching row already exists.
- It will delete and insert a row, not actually update it.  This might matter if you have triggers on the table or for some performance considerations.

Comment: Excellent, I never knew this. Seems like a decent alternative to constructing a SET string.